# Android Alarm Reminder

Tags: android, alarm

I have an app which is loading upcoming dates (like Birthdays) from an `SQLite` database
and showing it on a `ListView`. That works fine.
What I now want is to inform the user regular by an `Alarm` or `Toast` or something without
starting the application. The user has the only option when to inform: on the **same day** or **1 day before** and the **time**!
Has someone an idea how to realize this? Maybe a `Service` or a `Timer`, or both?
I would be very pleased about some tips.

Comment: Wrote a tutorial. Notification Reminders: http://blog.blundell-apps.com/notification-for-a-user-chosen-time/

Comment: Is this your problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look onto [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).  Also note that the service doesn't persist alarms between sessions so you'll need to [re-setup them](http://android.arnodenhond.com/tutorials/alarm-notification#TOC-Proximity-Alerts) after device boot. Another option may be using Google calendar API to create birthday events, notification will be handled by Google calendar app then.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick answer, i think google calender API is the best one for me. Do you know a trick to work with google calendar on virtual SDK device...

Comment: I don't know :) Also that's another question. Ask it if you need.